# Is okta supports wildcards in Origin URL to add in the trusted origin?

Tags: okta, okta-api

Is okta supports wildcards in Origin URL to add in the trusted origin ?

Comment: Hi vasu, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm having some trouble parsing your question, are you asking if okta supports adding wildcards in a trusted origin URL? It would be helpful to clean up the grammar for this question to encourage people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like Okta supports wildcards when adding urls to trusted origin but there is an API endpoint that might be help. https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/trusted-origins/#create-trusted-origin

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enter full URL in trusted origin. You can just add the hostname and all URL's with that hostname will be whitelisted.